# Angular computed observable with value from API

Tags: angular

I'm making (my first) Angular page for a user to edit a tree structure that's stored in JSON.

In `ngOnInit` I load the whole JSON tree from my API and set the `currentVertex` property of my component to the root vertex of the tree. (When the user moves to another vertex in the tree I cannot use routing to implement their click because `ngOnInit` would run again and so overwrite any changes they've made to the JSON object -- right?)

Next I need to load associated metadata in order to populate dropdowns etc. in the form for editing the selected veretx of the tree.

Can I do this with a computed observable (or whatever they're called in Angular)?
I seem to think it ought to go something like:

```
  get metadata() {
    return this.metadataService.metadata(this.selectedVertex.name);
  }
```

However, this causes errors of the form:

> `error TS2339: Property '...' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.`

I guess I need to do something with the value (whatever it is -- apparently it's not JSON) that is returned from `http.get(...)`, but what?

**Edit:**

Here is a service

```
export class SystemConfigurationService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  entityAllOptions(name) {
    return this.http.get("/SystemConfiguration/EntityAllOptions/" + name, {});
  }
```

How do I make the JSON returned from this into a computed observable on a component?

This doesn't work:

```
export class AppSystemConfigurationEntityComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private systemConfigurationService: SystemConfigurationService) {
  }
  
  name: string; // will be updated from a (click)

  get allOptions() {
    return this.systemConfigurationService.entityAllOptions(this.entityName).subscribe((data) => { console.log(data);});
  }
}
```

because when the template tries to use any property of `allOptions` it says

> `error TS2339: Property '...' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.`

**This doesn't work either**

```
  get allOptions() {
    //console.log('allOptionsLoad');
    this.systemConfigurationService.entityAllOptions(this.entityName).subscribe((data) => { this.allOptionsData= data; });
    return this.allOptionsData;
  }
  allOptionsData;
```

Why is it so bloody impossible to do something so simple? Wish I could use VueJS instead of this crap.

Answer (score 1):

Angular's HttpClient `http.get(...)` returns an observable to which you have to **SUBSCRIBE**.

Note: Http request is an async task, http.get returns a cold observable (nothing happens untill someone subscribes). so do not forget to subscribe

```
getData() {
  this.http.get(...).subscribe((data) => {
      // data is your required json from backend !!!
      console.log(data);
  });
}
```

do whatever you want with the data.

**EDIT**

> This doesn't work either
> It wont because you are trying to return data from http request before it arives. Please take cognizance of the fact that http requests are **ASYNC**.

Comment: accept the answer if it solved your issue. so that this might help others.

Comment: I've seen subscribe used in ngOnInit to put the result into a property -- that's how I get my big JSON tree., But here there isn't a separate property, so what do you do? Where do you put the data? ( Don't really want to spam the console every time I do an API call.)

Comment: The metadata of a vertex is not available in the initial big json u fetch? You want to fetch it when user moves to a vertex as a seperate http request?

Comment: Well indeed that's another question...

It's not feasible to fetch all the metadata at the start because the user's object relates to just a small subset of it -- so I will need to fetch more metadata when the user wants to add to their obkect.

Comment: This `.subscribe()` doesn't work. I now get: `error TS2339: Property '...' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.`

Comment: please post the code you are using. it is really very easy with angular to make and process http requests and responses. Please explain the requirement more clearly what u want to do and when

Comment: Have I not posted enough code? It's very simple: I want to make a computed observable that updates automatically when one of the properties upon which it depends is updated and its value is obtaned from an API.

Comment: A observable is not a value that should be updated. atleast not the one which is returned by an http request. Observables are just emitters, emitting values. do not try to make them do something else. Try maintaining a state (the config state) in the service and whenever u want to update or add do it to the state variable. Make a http request -> get data and append to state variable. user interaction -> update state variable. when u want to display something get it from this state variable